# Make tag badges in badges page more accessible

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, user-interface, tag-badges

I like the design of the new badges page, but one thing did stand out to me. I noticed on the new [earned badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=earned) page, tag badges appear just as they would on the [all badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=all) page:

[image: Tag Badges]

Obviously, you don't want to show all tag badges on the all badges page, but on earned badges, it makes since that would show what tag badges that I've actually earned, [like it does here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=earned). Preferably, it would list each badge grouped together with others for the same tag (just as it groups other badges together).

On a more general note, the fact that you have to click on 'bronze badge', 'silver badge' or 'gold badge' before you can filter them through the any of the other tabs seems odd. For example, I think if you are on 'all badges' and you click the header for 'tag badges' it should take you directly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=all), without having to take the intermediate step through the bronze/silver/gold-badge list. It certainly wasn't obvious to me how to find the full list of tag badges with the new design, and I only discovered it by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Nick Craver got this done last night. The fake tag badges in the list page now feature  a checkbox if you earned any in that class, and a global count on the right.

[image: changes example]

Comment: Thanks. That's a step in the right direction, but it's not actually what I was looking for. It doesn't show the actual badges (only the fake badges as you call them), nor does it provide a convenient way to link to the 'earned tag badges' page.