# New badges page is confused about the definition of "unearned"

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges

The [unearned list of tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=unearned) on the redesigned badges page shows me badges that I have indeed earned, even going so far as to point them out to me:

[image: unearned tab of new badges page]

The relevant tag badges also appear on the earned tab, so this is confusing.

I was also going to point out that there doesn't appear to be an intuitive way to get to the tag badge subview, but [someone's beaten me to the punch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184957/make-tag-badges-in-badges-page-more-accessible).

Comment: I didn't notice that when I was researching for my question, but good catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've decided this was a bug, and have checked in a fix for the next push.

Comment: What you're describing is for the general view, right, as opposed to the tag subview?

Comment: I might have misread your original post. It's getting late, so I'm going to refrain from making a judgment one way or the other, but I'll think it through for the next batch of tweaks.

Comment: @Jeremy I can get the reasoning, but it's confusing. "Unearned" doesn't mean "Can still earn it" to me, it means "have not earned it at all yet". Badges you can earn again fit the former definition, but not the latter. There's probably a better way to indicate a badge can still be earned further, such as an indication on the "Earned" tab.

Comment: Nobody is going to interpret "unearned" as "can be earned, even if I already have it"